# Can I use LINQ to compare ranges in two arrays?

Tags: c#, linq

I can roll a method, pseudo:

```
bool Compare(IList left, int lIndex, IList right, int rIndex, int num)
{
  for(int i=0;i<num;++i)
  {
   if(left[lIndex+i] != right[rIndex+i])
   {
    return false;
   }
  }
  return true;
}
```

So given `L =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and `R = [5,6,7,8,9]` : `Compare(L,5,R,1,3) == true`

I feel I should be able to do a simple LINQ version but I am not sure how to handle the indexing. Can it be written as a trivial LINQ/lambda... otherwise I'll pull this out as a utility method.

---

*By the way there is a question with a very similar title but it is asking a different thing: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812323/compare-two-arrays-using-linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812323/compare-two-arrays-using-linq_)*

Comment: Not at a compiler, but something like Left.Skip(3).Intersect(Right.Skip(1).Take(4))).Count() == 4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [`Skip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.8), [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.8), and [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.8):

```
return left.Skip(lIndex).Take(num).SequenceEqual(
        right.Skip(rIndex).Take(num))
```

Note that you should make your `Compare` method generic and use the generic `IList<T>` instead.

Comment: That's neat, thanks. It doesn't matter in my case but does this end up allocating new objects or does each operation return some sort of palce-holder to the original object?

Comment: @Mr.Boy It does create new objects that implement `IEnumerable`, although no new lists are created. They are basically a "view" on your original list. So I would expect this to have more overhead than your for loop.

Comment: OK but we're talking very light-weight objects designed for this kind of use... so I can live with that. Thankyou.

Comment: You should keep in mind that it'll work only with generic `IList<T>`, OP example uses non-generic `IList`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski my code is pseudo but thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
    int num = 3,lIndex =5,rIndex =1;

    var L = (new List<int>(){1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}).Skip(lIndex).Take(num).ToList();
    var R = (new List<int>(){5,6,7,8,9}).Skip(rIndex).Take(num).ToList();

    var result = L.Count() == R.Count() && !R.Except(L).Any() && !L.Except(R).Any() && string.Join(",",L).Equals(string.Join(",",R));
```